# How to delete a file from upload folder

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete a photo from upload folder when i press delete all records are deleted except the picture in upload folder here is my delete, how to i code the snippet to delete from upload folder

```
//trigger
<?php 
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?staff_id=' . $row['staff_id'] . '"><input type="button" onclick="confirmDelete(event)" value="delete">';

// check if the 'staff_id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
if (isset($_GET['staff_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['staff_id']))
{
    // get staff_id value       
    $staff_id = $_GET['staff_id'];

    // delete the entry
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM development WHERE staff_id=$staff_id") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Comment: You can use the [PHP unlink function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: This is the link to delete.php, you need to show the processing delete.php performs when the link is clicked. (Welcome also)

Comment: But what is after the `(isset($_GET['staff_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['staff_id']))`

Comment: How do i code the part to delete picture from upload folder using staff_id which is the name of the file eg 12.jpg

Answer (score 6):

In your `delete.php` script you would need a line like this :

```
unlink( "path_to_your_upload_directory/".$staff_id.".jpg" );
```

If you have various file extensions : One way to achieve it is to first save the filename with extension in an appropriate database table when the user/staff uploads the file . Retrieve the same and use it when deleting the file :

```
$filename_with_extension = 'retrieve this from database table where it is stored';
unlink( "path_to_your_upload_directory/".$filename_with_extension );
```

Comment: we should to check if file exists

Answer (score 1):

[unlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function in PHP. You have to provide full path to that file in parameter.

NOTE: Do not give `http://` path.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['staff_id'])&&is_numeric($_GET['staff_id']))
{
    $Staff_Id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['staff_id']);
    if($Staff_Id != '.' || $Staff_Id != '..')
    {
        $extension = '.jpg';
        if(unlink('uploads/'.$Staff_Id.$extension))
        {
            $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM development WHERE staff_id=$staff_id")or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may work but is asking for a nasty SQL-injection attack through `$staff_id`.

Comment: Indeed it is  but it's just an example  of  how he can unlink  the file but still i'll  modify my answer..

Comment: Actually, even then, you need to protect the `unlink` call (I was focused on the query earlier); this doesn't eliminate tricks like `..` in the path.

Comment: Anything else sire ;p

Comment: It worked when modified i have to put .jpg after the staff_id> How to i make it to delete any picture file that has any extension associated to a staff_id

Comment: unlink() function will delete anyfile no matter what's the extension of file .. for ex  if the file you want to delete is 11.jpg .. and  $staff_id = 11 ; then you'll delete the file like unlink($staff_id.'.jpg');

Comment: what if the file happens to be a .gif file and i accept jpg, gif, bng to be uploaded what do i puse to replace .jpg so that it can delete any file regardless of the extention gif, jpg, or bng

Answer (score 0):

Use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function. This will remove a file from the specified directory